# sporadic NullPointerException in CurrentModuleContainer.Get Asp .Net code when doing async handling

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await, asp.net-4.5

I have an Asp .Net application for which I'm using the new async/await paradigm with .net 4.5 RC.
I am using the new task-based async http handler `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` for handling http request. In my code i'm doing some I/O streaming a file to the client.

once in a while i'm getting a `NullPointerException` with the following stack trace:

> System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CurrentModuleContainer.get() + 0x1e bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0xb7 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(System.IAsyncResult ar) + 0x1f3 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() + 0x6e bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) + 0x1c5 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x1ea bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

This seems to happen after my code already returned the response.

When this happens the next request is just never handled, but the one after it is back to normal.

What could be the reason for this behavior? I took a peek at the source code for the CurrentModuleContainer.Get method and it seems that the only thing that can throw a null pointer exception is the Http context.

Comment: Can't help without the code, although a NullReferenceException means you tried to use a variable that is null.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698395/unobservedtaskexception-where-did-the-task-come-from

Answer (score 0):

The exception could come from many different reasons but one could guess that you are trying to access the current HttpContext in your handler, which might be null during async end function.