# UnobservedTaskException - Where did the task come from

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, task

In my MVC application, I sometimes get an exception like:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingRequestStream(RequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass4.<PrepareAndStartContentUpload>b__0(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

EDIT
Here's another kind I'm seeing:

```
System.Exception: Unhandled Task Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Here's what I see in the event log, but it's not exactly correlated in time or count.

```
A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205.

An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.
```

/EDIT

Is there a way to identify the source/location of the exception or get any other information about where the exception came from?

EDIT 2
Here's another one I'm seeing. They're all related to OnAsyncHandlerCompletion, but I'm not sure what the source is.

```
System.Exception: Unhandled Task Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_CurrentModuleContainer()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

/EDIT 2

Comment: Use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to get error messages from the http.  You can look at Administrative Tools : Event Viewer to get more details.

Comment: You don't know where your app makes http requests?

Comment: @jdweng Fiddler/wireshark would give some context, but I was looking for something that would help identify the location in code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I know the locations where it makes the requests. I'm trying to avoid going to every location to pepper it with try/catch just to hunt down a single location. This isn't a small/trivial CRUD app. :) Another benefit of being able to gather information at this location, or by altering the Task Scheduler, is that future issues could be identified easily without having to track down new places that make HTTP requests.

Comment: Does this reproduce only in prod or also in dev?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov only in production. Something seems to happen where all of a sudden I get hundreds of these exceptions all showing up at nearly the same time. I'm perplexed why they all get backed up and why it seems they're all getting dumped at the same time. I'm also unsure if it's my code or something I depend on. For example Azure DataCache (I'm using In-Role caching). Could it be something within that or some other component causing this issue?

Comment: Do you pass a timeout to your http requests? You might be experiencing latencies in Azure.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as transport layer.  If you are getting hundreds of exceptions it sounds like the connection was lost, and you continued to send data after the first exception occurred.  Your code should be modulized so all the request are done in one place to make it easier to track where the failure occurred.  You can tell the location of the failure by the http contents.  I would check the Event Viewer on the Server to find out why the server dropped the connection.

Comment: @dmarlow: It's possible -- although I'm not certain about this -- that the reason you're seeing hundreds of these at the same time is because the exceptions are only thrown when the runtime does a finalization run. Until that time the tasks just sit there; when the finalization happens it will churn through the tasks pretty rapidly and throw for all those with unobserved exceptions.

Comment: @LukeH that's what I've read from other similar posts. However, this doesn't help me to identify the source of the problems. The 2 edits I made above shows that this is happening in some async endpoint of mine, but have no clue as to why that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event, and perhaps get more information about the exception.

Comment: That's where I'm currently getting the exception from. I'm just logging it and was curious about its origins as it contains little useful information.

Comment: I'm still not finding a way to see the location of the original error. Also note the 'Object reference not found' does NOT mean that was your error in your code. I just verified this by explicitly throwing an unhandled exception that 'became' a null reference exception :-(